# Error in POM.xml file even after cleaning {users}/.m2/repository for *LastUpdated files

Tags: java, maven

I am getting this error in POM.xml. I tried cleaning *lastUpdated from .m2/repository still getting this error. Thanks in advance!

Failure to transfer org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.0.2 from http://illin5564.corp.amdocs.com:28080/repository/maven-public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of illin5564-nexus has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.0.2 from/to illin5564-nexus (http://illin5564.corp.amdocs.com:28080/repository/maven-public/): Access denied to http://illin5564.corp.amdocs.com:28080/repository/maven-public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.2/plexus-io-2.0.2.jar. Error code 401, Unauthorized

Comment: What is this strange repository you want to download from?

Comment: `Error code 401, Unauthorized` - so you need credentials to authorized against Nexus

Comment: I've already downloaded it from Bitbucket. The error is on local